# Why are there altitude differences on the Jeppesen ESB Ankara VOR chart?

Tags: approach, instrument-procedures, vor, non-precision-approach, jeppesen

What is the reason for the 10 feet difference between ESB dme altitude and profile view? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to post the Turkish version of this chart?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, since that is not the current chart, the following is speculation.

The altitudes in the table are the recommended altitudes for a continuous descent. The altitudes in the profile view are step down altitudes. The continuous descent information usually comes from the host nation’s aviation authority (i.e., not Jeppesen), but the current chart does not have these values. I do not know where Jeppesen got the 3.30 degree constant descent angle, unless they calculated it. That is permissible and is what must happen for the procedure to be coded into an FMS.